# Finding a better way to count matrices

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, math, numpy

I would like to count the number of 2d arrays with only 1 and 0 entries that have a disjoint pair of disjoint pairs of rows that have equal vector sums.  For a 4 by 4 matrix the following code achieves this by just iterating over all of them and testing each one in turn.

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations
n = 4
nxn = np.arange(n*n).reshape(n, -1)
count = 0
for i in xrange(2**(n*n)):
   A = (i >> nxn) %2
   p = 1
   for firstpair in combinations(range(n), 2):
       for secondpair in combinations(range(n), 2):
           if firstpair < secondpair and not set(firstpair) & set(secondpair):
              if (np.array_equal(A[firstpair[0]] + A[firstpair[1]], A[secondpair[0]] + A[secondpair[1]] )):
                  if (p):
                      count +=1
                      p = 0
print count
```

The output is 3136.

The problem with this is that it uses 2^(4^2) iterations and I would like to run it for n up to 8. Is there a cleverer way to count these without iterating over all the matrices?  For example it seems pointless to create permutations of the same matrix over and over again.

Comment: You want "two disjoint pairs of disjoint pairs of rows that have equal vector sums", or it's a typo and you meant "two disjoint pairs of rows that have equal vector sums" ?

Comment: @GastónBengolea Thanks. It is a pair of pairs not two pairs of pairs.

Comment: The matrix is any 2d matrix or one like the one you created right there?

Comment: @GastónBengolea I am considering all n by n matrices with entries that are 1 or 0. My code just iterates over those for n = 4.  I would like it to work for n=5,6,7,8 but it takes far too long currently.

Comment: executing a single cpu cycle for each 8x8 matrix would take roughly 10000 years on todays hardware; and as we discovered earlier, you need millions of cycles to check one matrix. So you really need to come up with something better than trying them all. Even modulo row/column permutations, my gut instinct tells me you are still in big trouble. You might get a good estimate of the total number of such matrices by stochastically sampling the space of all matrices?

Comment: For instance; 2276 out of 100.000 8x8 matrices test positive, which can be computed in a dozen or so seconds. Those kind of statistics should suffice at least to characterize the behavior of this property as a function of the matrix size. (edit; that was for triple-sums; its 7255/100.000 for double row sums)

Comment: I would have guessed triple sums are more common, but it does not seem like it. On the one hand we have more combinations to test, but on the other hand, the space in which these combinations fall is also bigger

Comment: One can find some interesting statistical facts quite rapidly using this method; for double sums, 6x6 matrices have the most hits, at more than 10%. For triple sums, this maximum shifts to n=8, with only ~2.2% hits. A 2d plot of n-m looks relatively constant along the m==n diagonal; even though it drops to zero pretty steadily for larger n, the odds change much more dramatically off-axis

Comment: @EelcoHoogendoorn  Take n = 6. There are only 74974368 different ways of choosing 6 distinct rows if we ignore matrices that are just row permutatations of each other. So I feel that should at least be doable somehow.

Comment: @EelcoHoogendoorn For n = 8 we get about 4 * 10^14 matrices invariant under row permutations. If each one really took a cpu cycle that would finish in less than a week I think :)

Comment: Is there any chance you're only interested in the vector sums modulo 2? Because then this becomes much easier.

Comment: @AndyJones That would be nice but sadly, no.

Comment: So you want to pick 4 rows, all of them disjoint and the componentwise sum of two of them equals the respective sum of the other two? you don't care about the remaining entries of the 2d field and all entries are ones or zeros? pretty sure this can be solved mathematically.

Comment: @example That would be great!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Computed in about a minute on my machine, with CPython 3.3:

```
4 3136
5 3053312
6 7247819776
7 53875134036992
8 1372451668676509696
```

Code, based on memoized inclusion-exclusion:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import collections
import itertools

def pairs_of_pairs(n):
    for (i, j, k, m) in itertools.combinations(range(n), 4):
        (yield ((i, j), (k, m)))
        (yield ((i, k), (j, m)))
        (yield ((i, m), (j, k)))

def columns(n):
    return itertools.product(range(2), repeat=n)

def satisfied(pair_of_pairs, column):
    ((i, j), (k, m)) = pair_of_pairs
    return ((column[i] + column[j]) == (column[k] + column[m]))

def pop_count(valid_columns):
    return bin(valid_columns).count('1')

def main(n):
    pairs_of_pairs_n = list(pairs_of_pairs(n))
    columns_n = list(columns(n))
    universe = ((1 << len(columns_n)) - 1)
    counter = collections.defaultdict(int)
    counter[universe] = (- 1)
    for pair_of_pairs in pairs_of_pairs_n:
        mask = 0
        for (i, column) in enumerate(columns_n):
            mask |= (int(satisfied(pair_of_pairs, column)) << i)
        for (valid_columns, count) in list(counter.items()):
            counter[(valid_columns & mask)] -= count
    counter[universe] += 1
    return sum(((count * (pop_count(valid_columns) ** n)) for (valid_columns, count) in counter.items()))
if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    for n in range(4, 9):
        print(n, main(n))
```

Comment: In case you become interested in values for n > 8, there's still a fair amount of symmetry that could be exploited by collapsing items of `valid_columns` whose keys are isomorphic under row permutations.

Comment: clever; ive thought about a solution along these lines, but got stuck

Comment: Very nice.  By modifying your code to handle the N rows x M columns case to get data to play with I think I've got (empirical) generating functions for N=4,5,6,7.  If I can crack the pattern I can at least conjecture values for higher N,M.

Comment: Bravo!  That's slick :-)

Comment: Thank you! Although this is above and beyond what SO asks for, could you possibly explain in mathematical terms what your code is computing? Can it be written as a simple sum for example? Also, do you know what its time complexity is?

Comment: @marshall It's computing the cardinality of a union via the [inclusion-exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion–exclusion_principle) where each set in the union is the set of binary matrices that satisfy a particular row equation (and possibly others). The number of n by m binary matrices that satisfy a particular set of row equations is the number of columns that satisfy that set to the power m. I don't know the complexity of this algorithm; it runs faster than 2**(2**n) only to the extent that there are many fewer distinct intersections that that.

Answer (score 3):

You can file this one under "better than nothing" ;-)  Here's plain Python3 code that rethinks the problem a bit.  Perhaps numpy tricks could speed it substantially, but hard to see how.

1. "A row" here is an integer in `range(2**n)`.  So the array is just a tuple of integers.
2. Because of that, it's dead easy to generate all arrays that are unique under row permutation via `combinations_with_replacement()`.  That reduces the trip count on the outer loop from `2**(n**2)` to `(2**n+n-1)-choose-n)`.  An enormous reduction, but still ...
3. A precomputed dict maps pairs of rows (which means pairs of integers here!) to their vector sum as a tuple.  So no array operations are required when testing, except to test the tuples for equality.  With some more trickery, the tuples could be coded as (say) base-3 integers, reducing the inner-loop test to comparing two integers retrieved from a pair of dict lookups.
4. The time and space required for that precomputed dict is relatively trivial, so no attempt was made to speed that part.
5. The inner loop picks row indices 4 at a time, instead of your pair of loops each picking two indices at a time.  It's faster to do all 4 in one gulp, in large part because there's no need to weed out pairs with a duplicated index.

Here's the code:

```
def calc_row_pairs(n):
    fmt = "0%db" % n
    rowpair2sum = dict()
    for i in range(2**n):
        row1 = list(map(int, format(i, fmt)))
        for j in range(2**n):
            row2 = map(int, format(j, fmt))
            total = tuple(a+b for a, b in zip(row1, row2))
            rowpair2sum[i, j] = total
    return rowpair2sum

def multinomial(n, ks):
    from math import factorial as f
    assert n == sum(ks)
    result = f(n)
    for k in ks:
        result //= f(k)
    return result

def count(n):
    from itertools import combinations_with_replacement as cwr
    from itertools import combinations
    from collections import Counter
    rowpair2sum = calc_row_pairs(n)
    total = 0
    class NextPlease(Exception):
        pass
    for a in cwr(range(2**n), n):
        try:
            for ix in combinations(range(n), 4):
                for ix1, ix2, ix3, ix4 in (
                       ix,
                       (ix[0], ix[2], ix[1], ix[3]),
                       (ix[0], ix[3], ix[1], ix[2])):
                    if rowpair2sum[a[ix1], a[ix2]] == \
                       rowpair2sum[a[ix3], a[ix4]]:
                        total += multinomial(n, Counter(a).values())
                        raise NextPlease
        except NextPlease:
            pass
    return total
```

That sufficed to find results through n=6, although it took a long time to finish the last one (how long? don't know - didn't time it - on the order of an hour, though - "long time" is relative ;-) ):

```
>>> count(4)
3136
>>> count(5)
3053312
>>> count(6)
7247819776
```

**EDIT - removing some needless indexing**

A nice speedup by changing the main function to this:

```
def count(n):
    from itertools import combinations_with_replacement as cwr
    from itertools import combinations
    from collections import Counter
    rowpair2sum = calc_row_pairs(n)
    total = 0
    for a in cwr(range(2**n), n):
        for r0, r1, r2, r3 in combinations(a, 4):
            if rowpair2sum[r0, r1] == rowpair2sum[r2, r3] or \
               rowpair2sum[r0, r2] == rowpair2sum[r1, r3] or \
               rowpair2sum[r0, r3] == rowpair2sum[r1, r2]:
                total += multinomial(n, Counter(a).values())
                break
    return total
```

**EDIT - speeding the sum test**

This is minor, but since this seems to be the best exact approach on the table so far, may as well squeeze some more out of it.  As noted before, since each sum is in `range(3)`, each tuple of sums can be replaced with an integer (viewing the tuple as giving the digits of a base-3 integer).  Replace `calc_row_pairs()` like so:

```
def calc_row_pairs(n):
    fmt = "0%db" % n
    rowpair2sum = dict()
    for i in range(2**n):
        row1 = list(map(int, format(i, fmt)))
        for j in range(2**n):
            row2 = map(int, format(j, fmt))
            total = 0
            for a, b in zip(row1, row2):
                t = a+b
                assert 0 <= t <= 2
                total = total * 3 + t
            rowpair2sum[i, j] = total
    return rowpair2sum
```

I'm sure numpy has a much faster way to do that, but the time taken by `calc_row_pairs()` is insignificant, so why bother?  BTW, the advantage to doing this is that the inner-loop `==` tests change from needing to compare tuples to just comparing small integers.  Plain Python benefits from that, but I bet pypy could benefit even more.

Comment: Does pypy speed this up out of interest?

Comment: Don't know about pypy - no version of pypy works with Python3 yet.  And, while it might seem odd, I stick to pure standard out-of-the-box Python when tackling "hard" problems (no pypy, no numpy, no external packages).  Why?  Because it's so frickin' slow it *forces* you to think of cleverer approaches :-)

Comment: Actually.. that makes perfect sense to me :)

Comment: Just FYI your code is actually also in python 2.x it seems and works just fine with pypy and takes 17 minutes for n = 6.

Comment: @TimPeters  wow, nice speedup. has marshall verified the n=5 or n=6 answeres? BTW I might take a look at a numpy or numba solution. Can't imagine it wouldn't be a speedup with "fancy indexing".  That's just talk unless I post one so nice job!

Comment: @PhilCooper, after the last edit the `rowpair2sum` dict is now indexed by a pair of integers and returns an integer - perfect fit for a 2d numpy array.  But *huge* speedups require a different approach.  I'm trying to view it as a mathematical inclusion-exclusion problem, but my head keeps getting twisted into knots ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer to your question, but as I noted, I think you can safely forget about exhaustively testing all matrices for any significant n. But the problem lends itself well to a stochastic characterization. Interestingly, under some conditions triple sums are more common than double sums! The likelihood of getting a hit appears to be a fairly simple (monotone) function of both n and m though, no surprises there.

[image: double sums; n,m = 4..20]

[image: triple sums; n,m = 4..20]

Comment: Could you explain your pictures a little please? Also when you say "under some conditions triple sums are more common than double sums" that seems surprising. What sort of conditions?

Comment: Somehow the image captions don't show up. Top image is double sums, bottom image is triple sums, with 10.000 samples per cell. vertical axis is n, horizontal axis is m, running from 4 to 20 inclusive. red is 100% hits, blue is 0% hits. At the bottom row (n=20), we may see the triple sums showing up more than the double sums; at least for moderate m. triple sums seem to fall off more shapely with bigger m too, so that may not hold true for all m.

Comment: In the region around n=300,m=20, you are virtually sure to have a triple hit, and sure not to have a double hit; and this contrast can be pushed arbitrarily high. The converse scenario does not appear to manifest itself anywhere in the parameter space. Double hits are more common for n<=m, but they never dominate in the same way.